# Is there a way to make Caps Lock act as the left Shift key?

Tags: windows-7

When gaming, I oftentimes hit the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key when I mean to hit the <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> key. This (obviously) causes undesired effects:

- Causes me too look like a noob when I fail to make the correct action, and
- Causes me to yell at people the next time I type unless I take the time to press it again.

Is there a way (in Windows) to force the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key to mimic the <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> key, either at all times or at least when games are active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third-party keyboard layout and mapping tools are available that will allow you to change the behavior of the Caps Lock key, but many of these really boil down to a .reg file, which edits the Windows registry for you. In general, these .reg files are fine and come from people and organizations just trying to help make your life easier, but it still involves a stranger editing your Windows registry files.

Refer the below link for more details:-

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/how-do-i-turn-off-the-caps-lock-key-in-windows-7/

Answer (score 1):

Use a key remapping program like [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

These days, I would highly recommend [PowerToys' Keyboard Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/keyboard-manager) for this task, if for some reason your keyboard doesn't already come with software that can handle it (or if the software it does come with is bulky).

[PowerToys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) is an official Microsoft application and provides lots of useful and/or niche functionality that isn't included in Windows by default.